# Why does $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\cos 1/x}$ fluctuate between $0$ and $\infty$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I graphed the function

$$y = x^{\cos(1/x)}$$

in matplotlib and realized that much like $\displaystyle y = \sin(\frac1x)$, the function has no limit as $x\to0^+$. However, $y = x^{\cos(1/x)}$ fluctuates between 0 and $+\infty$.

$$0^0=1$$
Neither of which approaches infinity. Why is $\displaystyle y$ bounded by infinity and 0 as x approaches 0?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=1/(2n\pi)$ where $n$ is an integer, then
$$x^{\cos(1/x)}=x\to0\quad\hbox{as $n\to\infty$}.$$
If $x=1/((2n+1)\pi)$ then
$$x^{\cos(1/x)}=x^{-1}\to\infty\quad\hbox{as $n\to\infty$}.$$
So for various (positive) values of $x$, your expression oscillates between $0$ and $\infty$.